Adding a temporal table to an existing table
I have an existing application in production that I didn't initially set up with Temporal Tables enabled. Now I am trying to add them to the schema by modifying my IEntityTypeConfiguration file for the tables and it isn't working as expected.
For example:
public class LineConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Line>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Line> builder)
    {
        // Temporal table setup
        builder.ToTable(b => b.IsTemporal());

        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDefaultValueSql($"NEXT VALUE FOR {BillOfLadingDbContext.LineIdSequence}")
            .HasColumnOrder(0);

        // Auditing
        builder.Property(x => x.Created)
            .HasColumnOrder(1);

        builder.Property(x => x.Modified)
            .HasColumnOrder(2);

        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy)
            .HasColumnOrder(3);

        builder.Property(x => x.ModifiedBy)
            .HasColumnOrder(4);

        // Versioning
        builder.Property(x => x.Version)
            .IsRowVersion()
            .HasColumnOrder(5);

        // Soft-delete
        builder.Property(x => x.IsDeleted)
            .HasColumnOrder(6);

        // Property settings
        builder.Property(x => x.Quantity)
            .HasColumnOrder(7);

        builder.Property(x => x.UnitOfMeasureId)
            .HasColumnOrder(8);

        builder.Property(x => x.Ordinal)
            .HasDefaultValue(999)
            .HasColumnOrder(9);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.UnitOfMeasure)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UnitOfMeasureId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        builder.HasMany(x => x.LineItems);
    }
}

It fields the following code in the Migration:
b.ToTable(tb => tb.IsTemporal(ttb =>
                        {
                            ttb.UseHistoryTable("LinesHistory");
                            ttb
                                .HasPeriodStart("PeriodStart")
                                .HasColumnName("PeriodStart");
                            ttb
                                .HasPeriodEnd("PeriodEnd")
                                .HasColumnName("PeriodEnd");
                        }));

However, I don't see any temporal table generated from this migration (expecting "LinesHistory") after updating my database:

There's no PeriodStart or PeriodEnd fields and there's no LinesHistory table created.
I could run some manual SQL to alter the table in a migration but I'd prefer to understand why this isn't working how I thought.

So I was able to track down the source of the issues.
tl;dr
The code above is correct. However, I failed to roll back the DbContextModelSnapshot class from a previous migration I had deleted.
More Details
I was testing out different migrations and had been building and deleting the migration files. However, I failed to notice at some point that a migration I ran had changed the ModelSnapshot.
This had the unfortunate side effect of making future migrations not do everything they were supposed to do. In this case, that was to set the attributes of the table to point to a history table.
One I reverted my DbContextModelSnapshot to my main branch's and re-created the migration, it built as I expected and created the temporal table as I wanted it to.
